# Using Jmeter for load test:why "Record and Replay" method?

Tags: jmeter

I am a beginner working on jmeter. I am confused between the "Record and replay" method & the basic load test method (giving the url in the path and executing the test). Need help to distinguish between both - if possible with a good tutorial suggestion. Also how to do a "stress test" in the simplest  way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main idea behind web applications load testing is: **your test must represent real user activities as close as possible**.

How you implement it - it's up to you.

- If you know exactly which requests you need to mimic - you're more than welcome to develop your test by manually adding [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers.
- For those who are not very familiar with [HTTP protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) it might be easier to go "record and replay" way. But remember, the chance that you will be able to successfully replay recorded test scenario is minimal, most probably your will have to perform **correlation** - handling dynamic request parameters.

With regards to tutorials, normally you should start with [JMeter User Manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/), especially pay attention to the following chapters:

- [Building a Web Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html)
- [Building an Advanced Web Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-adv-web-test-plan.html)

You can also consider [JMeter Academy](https://www.blazemeter.com/jmeter-tutorial) - probably the fastest way of ramping up on JMeter

Comment: I created a Test plan for a web application with following transaction controllers:1.Launch and Login to the application 2.View the records in the page . Step 1- record & replay the transaction controller-1  .Step 2: add the 2nd transaction controller --> select it from the 'HTTPS SCRIPT RECORDER' -->record(only the view records actions) -->replay (by selecting transaction controller-2 and clicking on play button).I am able to find that both the transaction controllers can be seen in the View results tree after replay.How can I avoid this?I want only the 2nd set of transactions to be replayed.

Comment: Please note: In addition to the transaction controllers I have included the following elements under the thread group-  HTTP request(with home page url and port), HTTP request defaults, a CSV data set(with user login credentials) and a set of listeners (which are cleared after the replay of each transaction controller). Please advice ..